# AWS Amplify & Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am a beginner in AWS Amplify and Android both. I am trying to create a login app with AWS Amplify (more specifically AWS API Gateway).

I am getting stuck on how to create this app. I have used the CLI to create a REST API that will connect to my lambda function. That lambda function should interact with my DynamoDB table.

I want to get the email and password information and pass it to the DynamoDB table through API Gateway.

Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you created the REST API using the Amplify CLI, then you probably ran a command like:

```
amplify add api
```

If that's the case, then you can run:

```
amplify update api
```

to update the auth settings on your Amplify REST API. Here is some more information on how to [define authorization rules](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/authz/q/platform/android).